# How do i search through an Arraylist

Tags: apache-flex, arraylist

Sorry i am very weak in flex.
I would like to create an arraylist and i would like to create a search so if the vaules typed match the vaules in the arraylist .

Answer (score 1):

You can operate source array using [`source` property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayList.html#source) and then apply [`every`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#every%28%29) or [`filter`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter%28%29) method on array depending on quantity of matching values you want to obtain (first or all matching values).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the getItemIndex() function to search for a value?

```
ary = new ArrayList( [ "a", "b", "c"] ); // Create a list
hasValue = ary.getItemIndex("a") >= 0; // Check whether "a" is in list
```

If you don't need THE ArrayList then it is even simpler:

```
ary = [ "a", "b", "c"]; // Create a list
hasValue = ary.indexOf("a") >= 0; // Check whether "a" is in list
```

If you need a strict type match then you have to loop the list as Constantiner suggested.

Comment: oh i think what i meant was in the front end i have a textbox,label and a button when type either a , b or c on the text box it should appear in the label hello

Comment: Hmm. Do you mean when the user type something that is in a (hidden) list of values the label would say something, or do you mean if the text match part of something (e.g. part of a string) then the label would update?  Do you want to show 'hello' or do you want to show the stuff that matches?

Comment: when the user type something that matches something in the array list the word hello should appear